# How do i assign a defined variable as a key while updating by object?

Tags: javascript, object, dom

For instance, in this function even if i already assigned the value of a. The program considers a as An individual letter and does not add the value assigned to it in the html program.

```
let obj={}

function reg() {
let a = document.getElementById('user').value 
let b = document.getElementById('pass').value
obj.a=b
```

}

Output= a:the assigned value for b

Pls clarify my doubt.

Comment: square brackets instead of a dot. `obj[a] = b`. The content of the brackets is evaluated as an expression, and its result is used as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there this problem should be solved by

```
obj[a]=b
```

This is because the object.key method only works if the key is already present in the object

Happy coding and do let me know if you have any queries!

Comment: Whether or not the key already present has no impact on how the `object.key` syntax works.